# Append principal to bucket policy document instead overwrite it

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm developing a SPA with several envs: dev, preprod, prod

Each env have a corresponding CloudFront distribution and bucket website.

We also have a static website with user manual that is served on behavior /documentation/*

This static website is stored on a separate bucket

All environments share the same documentation, so there is only one bucket for all envs.

The project is a company portal, so user documentation should not be accessible publicly.

To achieve that, we are using OAI, so bucket is accessible only **through** CloudFront (a lambda@edge ensure user has a valid token and redirect him otherwise, so the documentation is private).

Everything is fine when I deploy on dev using

```sh
terraform workspace select dev
terraform apply -var-file=dev.tfvars
```

But when I try to deploy on preprod

```sh
terraform workspace select preprod
terraform apply -var-file=preprod.tfvars
```

Terraform changes OAI ID this way

```
  # module.s3.aws_s3_bucket_policy.documentation_policy will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "documentation_policy" {
        bucket = "my-bucket"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  ~ {
                        Action    = "s3:GetObject"
                        Effect    = "Allow"
                      ~ Principal = {
                          ~ AWS = "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3U64NEVQ9IQHH" -> "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3ORU58OAALJAP"
                        }
                        Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
                        Sid       = ""
                    },
                ]
                Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
    }
```

Whereas I would like the principal to added this way:

```
  # module.s3.aws_s3_bucket_policy.documentation_policy will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "documentation_policy" {
        bucket = "my-bucket"
      ~ policy = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              Statement = [
                  {
                        Action    = "s3:GetObject"
                        Effect    = "Allow"
                        Principal = {
                          AWS = "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3U64NEVQ9IQHH"
                        }
                        Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
                        Sid       = ""
                    },
                  + {
                  +     Action    = "s3:GetObject"
                  +     Effect    = "Allow"
                  +     Principal = {
                  +       AWS = "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E3ORU58OAALJAP"
                  +     }
                  +     Resource  = "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
                  +     Sid       = ""
                  + },
                ]
                Version   = "2012-10-17"
            }
        )
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this using terraform 0.13.5

For information, here is my `documentation-bucket.tf` which I import in each workspace once created

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "documentation" {
  bucket = var.documentation_bucket

  tags = {
    BillingProject = var.billing_project
    Environment    = var.env
    Terraform      = "Yes"
  }

  logging {
    target_bucket = var.website_logs_bucket
    target_prefix = "s3-access-logs/${var.documentation_bucket}/"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "documentation" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.documentation.arn}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "documentation_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.documentation.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.documentation.json
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumptions:

Based on what you said it seems you manage the same resource in different state files (assumption based on "[...] which I import in each workspace once created")

You basically created a split-brain situation by doing so.

Assumption number two: you are deploying a single S3 bucket and multiple CloudFront distributions accessing this single bucket all in the same AWS Account.

#### Answer:

While it is totally fine to do so, this is not how it is supposed to be set up. A single resource should only be managed by a single terraform state (workspace) or you will see this **expected** but unwanted behavior of having an unstable state.

I would suggest to manage the S3 bucket in a single workspace configuration or even create a new workspace called 'shared'.

In this workspace, you can use [terraform_remote_state data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to import the state of the other workspaces and build a policy including all your OAIs extracted from the other states. Of course, you can do so without creating a new shared workspace.

I hope this helps, while it might not be the expected solution - and maybe my assumptions are wrong.

#### Last words:

It's not considered good practice to share resources between environments, as data will most likely stay when you decommission environments, and managing access can get complex and insecure.

Better keep versions of the environments as close as possible like in [Dev/Prod Parity of the 12 factors app](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity), But try not to share resources. If you feel you need to share resources, take some time, and challenge your architecture again.

Comment: Hi mariux, thanks for this clear and detailed answer
Your assomptions were correct, ,I shared the "documentation" bucket between env, as user manual is he same.
However, I decided to use one documentation bucket / env, so it can be updated independently and we avoid the error-prone management of a single resource throgh several terraform workspaces